# What is the use of file descriptor 255 in bash process

Tags: linux, io-redirection

Executing the command below to display the file descriptors owned by the current process shows 4 file descriptors. File descriptors 0, 1, and 2 are stdin, stdout and stderr. What is file descriptor 255?

```
ls /proc/$$/fd
```

Output:

```
0  1  2  255
```

Comment: This question would be better asked at unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why would you need to post an image in this question? Can't you just paste the text output of the command?

Comment: @Barmar That's why i have added linux tag with this question.

Comment: You used the `Code Snippet` tool, it looks like `[<>]`. This is used for putting executable HTML/Javascript into your question. Use the `{}` tool to mark code in other languages.

Comment: @AmanJain stackoverflow is for programming related questions, not OS related questions (like superuser, unix.stackexcange.com, etc)

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie I am using file descriptor (fd) in python program to change standard in,out and err, using { os module } while working on that i got this issue. So, i asked here.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475389/ .

Answer (score 23):

*The open files are 0 (stdin), 1 (stdout), and 2 (stderr). 255 is a little trick that bash uses to keep a copy of these for when they are redirected. This is specific to bash.*

Source: https://books.google.com/books?id=wWjqCF9HLfYC&pg=PA231

Example:

```
echo foo 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null >/proc/$$/fd/255
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Comment: _keep a copy of these_ is poor wording in the book - as if one file descriptor could keep a copy of a plurality of _open files_.