# What copies does the bash(or zsh) keep when redirect?

Tags: bash, unix, redirect, file-descriptor

I try to implement pipeline and redirection in shell.

I try `ls -l /proc/$$/fd and lsof -p $$` command, i see 10u in zsh and 255u in bash.

So I found this question and read, [What is the use of file descriptor 255 in bash process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729906/what-is-the-use-of-file-descriptor-255-in-bash-process)
, but i didn't understand "255 is a little trick that bash uses to keep a copy of these for when they are redirected.".

What is the **"keep a copy"** of these for when redirected? Is that standard output?

Comment: Maybe state your real problem. Or is it just curiosity to know how shells perform redirection?

Comment: @gejo - The best answer I found is [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475396/43764) - sadly neither most-upvoted nor accepted.