# How to sed output of a command and not supress output

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have the example text stored in `test.sh`:

```
echo 'Hello world 123'
echo 'some other text'
```

With the following command in a bash script:

`word123=$(./test.sh |sed -nr 's/Hello world (.*)/\1/p' )`

This works correctly and outputs:

`123`

However, this does output

```
Hello world 123
some other text
```

Is there a way to capture the text in `123` and also output everything else in the file?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Using Ubuntu @Cyrus

Comment: `This works correctly and outputs:` There should be no output - all output is redirected to `word123`. Where is the output coming from?

Comment: What do you mean by "capture the text in `123` and also output everything else"?  Do you mean that you want to assign `123` to the variable while also printing the output of `./test.sh` to the output stream of the script?

Comment: jipot: First capture the output of `test.sh` somewhere (a variable, or a file). Then use this stored data for doing your `sed` replacement. Afterwards do with the unmodified data whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **Linux**, `bash` and `tee`:

```
word123=$( ./test.sh | tee >&255 >(sed -nr 's/Hello world (.*)/\1/p') )
```

File descriptor 255 is a non-redirected copy of stdout.

See: [What is the use of file descriptor 255 in bash process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729906/3776858)