# transform stream sent to a file by tee

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, pipe, tee

I want to redirect the stdout and stderr of a stream both to the screen and a file. For that I'm using the tool `tee`. However, before that stream goes to the file, I want to transform it using a pipe. So far, I have only managed to transform the stream that goes to stdout.

Example:

`echo 'hello' | tee output.txt | tr 'h' 'e'`

=> this will output `eello` to stdout and save `hello` to output.txt

However what I want is to print `hello` to stdout and save `eello` to output.txt.

Note: Changing the input stream is not an option for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in a single `awk` without multiple pipes:

```sh
echo 'hello' | awk '1; {gsub(/h/, "e"); print > "output.txt"}'
```

Comment: With this idea of completeness with `sed`: `echo 'hello' | sed -n 'p; s/h/e/g; w output.txt'`

Comment: Yup that's a good one @Cyrus

Answer (score 4):

With `bash`:

```
echo 'hello' | tee >(tr 'h' 'e' > output.txt)
```

With `bash` and Linux:

```
echo 'hello' | tee /proc/$$/fd/255 | tr 'h' 'e' > output.txt
```

See: [What is the use of file descriptor 255 in bash process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729906/3776858)

Comment: the mistake I was making was adding an additional space between `>` and `(` which is apparently illegal in bash.